# java regex parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I tried to split a propositional formula to severals sub-formulas in java. Can I use regex or should I write a parser? My grammar is only composed of literal symbols (A, B, C,...) and connectors (|, &, =>, <=>, not)

Example 1:

```
"((A | B) & (B | C))" :

array[0]= (A | B) 
array[1]=    &
array[2]= (B | C)
```

Example 2:

```
"((A => B) => (B | C)) & (B => A)" :

array[0]= (A => B) 
array[1]=    =>
array[2]= (B | C) 
array[3]=    &
array[4]= (B => A)
```

Comment: Probably you'll need to write a parser, but I can't be positive because it's unclear what rules you are applying to decide what the results should be in your two examples.  Writing out the rules in prose would be a good first step.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In fact, I try to split my formula to sub-formula to build a semantic tableau

Comment: @JohnBollinger Otherwise, it can be nice if I can get the 'middle' connector. For example "&" in the two formula.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works on the examples given:

```
(?:\([^()]+\))++|(?:&|<?=>|\|)++
```

https://regex101.com/r/NSQ9aZ/3

matches a string starting with a ( and ending with a ). Also matches &,|,=>,<=>, not